# text extraction from bank statements from pdf format

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr, parsing

I have bank statement memos containing transaction tables I need to extract. I only need to extract the transactions list. I have tried to use the Amazon text extractor, LayoutLM but since every bank has different formats, These models don't work well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most convenient way to do that in Python is by using a [tabula](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) library. I happened to do similar task with pdf files and probably the easiest way to do so is to use ***tabula.read_pdf*** function. I see also that Tabula has an online tool, but I haven't tried it.

Unless it works, you can try to create a parser a little more manually with [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) library. I can also recommend just asking ChatGPT to write a parser for you based on a snippet of your document. However, with this approach remember to anonymize your personal data.